# i would like to remove the underscore in the column headers of datagrid in silver light

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, header

- select me as "you are the best" from table;

but datagrid header displays

- you_are_the_best

### how should i stop this underscore??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void dataGrid2_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        e.Column.Header = ((string)e.Column.Header).Replace("_", " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the columns at compile time, you'll need to handle the [AutoGeneratingColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event as in the following example:

```
<data:DataGrid ItemsSource="..." AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="FormatColumnHeader">
</data:DataGrid>

private void FormatColumnHeader(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  e.Column.Header = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
column.Header = "your header"
```

or

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="your header"/>
```

Is this what you mean?